# 404 Error with Java Httpclient org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut

Tags: httpclient, http-status-code-404

I have proxy setup in my System properties. In my java app, using Apache HttpClient to HttpPut a file to a URL, with the following code. all 3 ways I tried to create a client return 404. This same works well with just HttpClients.getDefault() when there i no proxy setup. How do I fix this? Appreciate your help. thanks

```
 public void sendHTTPPutRequest(@NotNull HttpPut req)
            throws DataExtractException {
        try (CloseableHttpClient client = buildClient(req.getURI());
                CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(req)) {
           // ........
            }
    }

 private CloseableHttpClient buildClient(URI uri) {
    Proxy firstProxy = ProxySelector.getDefault().select(uri).get(0);        
    InetSocketAddress proxyAddress = (InetSocketAddress) firstProxy.address();
    HttpHost proxy = (proxyAddress == null || firstProxy.equals(Proxy.NO_PROXY)) ? null
            : new HttpHost(proxyAddress.getHostName(), proxyAddress.getPort());
    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    return HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore).setProxy(proxy).build();

    // NOTE: Here I also tried HttpClients.createSystem(), and HttpClients.getDefault()
    //  all 3 clients returned 404.

}
```